# How to implement timer in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm going to start timer after the button was clicked.

This is part of my code.

```
Device.StartTimer (TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), () => {
        int es = (int)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000%60;
        int em = (int)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000 / 60;
        timeLabel.Text = "Elapsed Time: \n" + em+"m "+es+"s";
        avgLabel.Text = "Average Time: \n" +(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000/(float)LessonMenu.drillList.Count).ToString()+"s";

        return true;
});
```

This works well, anyhow if multiple buttons are existing, the timer gets faster.
Does anybody have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can try the following code.

```
public static Stopwatch sw=new Stopwatch();

int elapsedSec = (int)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000%60;
int elapsedMin = (int)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000 / 60;
timeLabel.Text = "Elapsed Time: \n" + elapsedMin+"m "+elapsedSec+"s";
```

Comment: That seems to be the solution, let me try it.